# Assigning values based on existing numeric values in a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would want to implement the following logic in pandas:

if df['xxx'] <= 0 then df['xyz']== 'a'

if df['xxx'] between 0.5 and 10.97 then df['xyz']== 'b'

if df['xxx'] between 11 and 89.57 then df['xyz']== 'c'

if df['xxx'] > 100 then df['xyz']== 'd'

How can I do this in the simplest way?

Much thanks.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: see `pd.cut`...

Comment: @Junkrat, I thought of using np.where, but that's good for binary classification. I couldn't find anything else for my type of problem.

Comment: Check this out: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/56668/pandas-change-value-of-a-column-based-another-column-condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function and use apply method

```
def fun(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return 'a'
    elif (0 < x <= 1000):
        return  'b'
    elif (1000 < x):
        return  'c'

np.random.seed(3)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(xxx=np.random.choice([-1, 10, 2000],1000)))
df['xyz'] = df.xxx.apply(fun)
df.head(3)

#    xxx    xyz
# 0  2000   c
# 1  -1     a
# 2  10     b
```

Answer (score 1):

df['xyz'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'a' if x['xxx'] <=0 else ('b' if x['xxx'] < 1000 else 'c' ))

there might be syntax errors